# AngularJS Select Mutiple - How to submit the id and not and not the entire object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a multi select as follows:

```
<select 
    class="form-control" 
    ng-model="formData.selected_tests" 
    multiple="true"
    ng-multiple="true"
    ng-options="c.test for c in tests"
    id="tests"
    ng-attr-size="<% tests.length %>">
</select>
```

The `test` object contains `id`, `test` and `length` attributes.

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    console.log($scope.formData);

    $http.post('/api/v2/test', $scope.formData)
      .success(function(data) { })
  .error(function(data){ })
}
```

When I submit the form, I want formData.selected_tests to only contain an array of the selected `id` attributes. I dont want to submit the entire `test` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `select as label for value in array` syntax, in your case as:

```
<select
    ...
    ng-options="c.id as c.test for c in tests"
>
```

This will place the `id` in `formData.selected_tests` instead of the entire object. If you need the entire object somewhere, then you will have to transform the sent data, e.g. with a function:

```
$http.post('/api/v2/test', transform($scope.formData))
```

`transform()` will create a new object like `formData`, but will replace the tests with their ids. Using `angular.copy()` may be convenient.